# Table record count to unix log file

Tags: oracle, unix

I need the count of records of a data base table from unix.

I am calling one sql script from unix and need the record count to any log file .

Answer (score 1):

You can put the following into a `test.sql` file:

```
SET HEADING OFF;
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dual;
QUIT;
```

and call it via [SQL*Plus](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/SQL*Plus_FAQ) via script.

It will output:

```
         1
```

since table `dual` has only one row. You should be able to write that into a log file.

Answer (score 1):

You cant to append the output off your script to a named file by rediecting it like this.

```
$  sqlplus username/password@SID @your_script.sql >> /tmp/whatever.log
```

If your want to have more than a bald count in the output you'll need to include the boilerplate in the projectors:

```
SQL> select to_char(sysdate, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')||'::Number of emps = '
  2         , count(*)
  3  from emp
  4  group by to_char(sysdate, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')||'::Number of emps = '
  5  /

TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS   COUNT(*)
--------------------------------- ----------
20100210133747::Number of emps =          16

SQL>
```